# SpringBoot BeanCurrentlyInCreationException but not on another module without SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

In my web application I am using the following Spring version:

```
<org.springframework-version>3.2.9.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

I have a lot of beans which depends one of another and form cycle but there is no problem and I can use

```
@Autowired
SampleBean bean
```

without any problem.

Now I am trying to create rest service with usage of

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Unfortunately when I try to inject beans from another module I get exception:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'beanDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanDao': Bean with name 'beanDao' has been injected into other beans [beanA,beanB] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped
```

How to solve it? Why I am getting this error on SpringBoot but not on web app without usage of SpringBoot?

Comment: Maybe get rid of circular references

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing all the code that's involved. Perhaps you could create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve) is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Spring has already injected 'beanDao' into 'beanA' and 'beanB'. Now it wraps the bean, supposedly into a proxy and throws the exceptions.

'beanA' and 'beanB' would not use that proxy, but the raw bean, which cannot be wanted. That why spring raises the exception.

As you say this works before, it looks like something in the new dependency is creating this proxy.

You can try to find out, what causes the proxy and somehow disable it.
Or, even better, get rid of the cycle in the bean dependency.